# Spring Security and CSRF attack

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, csrf

I am working on a java web application which should be very secure, so I applied the spring security and spring MVC with CSRF enabled on SSL server; I used POST to submit all Forms along with the generated CSRF token successfully, however some pages have GET methods and if any attacker open the source of any page from any browser he can see the generated CSRF token inside the Form tag, then he can use it to POST any content to our site as long as the session is active by the user under attack !! am I right?

What should I do make the site very secure? should I use any other open source along with spring security to cover other attacks like cross site scripting, etc.. ? and should I enforce all pages to use POST to avoid any CSRF attack?

**UPDATE**

I tried to do more testing by submitting a request via client tool on the same browser under same session using same token as logged in user, but it fails, the response said login failed, and header contains nosniff

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

So I think it is safe using GET in spring security to handle the csrf without afraid from some one reading the token in GET pages, unless the attacker used XSS attack to do the submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attacker can see his own CSRF token, but he cannot see the CSRF token of another user.  Different users have different tokens, and using the wrong token should not work.

So there is nothing to be worried about here.  Don't panic.

Comment: If the attacker put scripts to read the GET page while the victim session is open(for example displaying an Ad that reads some GET pages), he can read the sensitive data of that page and can steal the token inside any POST action inside that page and use it to do POST actions.

Comment: @HanySakr, yes, but if the attacker can post scripts, then CSRF is one of the last things that will be on his mind.  There are going to be other, more serious and direct things that he can do in this scenario, such as dropping a [JavaScript key logger](https://wiremask.eu/articles/xss-keylogger-turorial/) to steal user passwords.  Think of it this way: CSRF works on a user-by-user basis, but cross-site scripting attacks many users at once.  Cross site scripting is much more dangerous than CSRF.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I need to close the door for any attacks, I am already handled the cross site scripting, and thinking If I could change all pages to POST, instead of GET, it will cover the CSRF completely, and will not allow any one to guess the generated token.
I saw one solution that generates token for each page like HDiv but is I don't know if it is integrated with spring security or not ?

Answer (score 0):

> however some pages have GET methods and if any attacker open the
>   source of any page from any browser he can see the generated CSRF
>   token inside the Form tag, then he can use it to POST any content to
>   our site as long as the session is active by the user under attack !!
>   am I right?

Yes you are right, Using GET will make your website leak the sensitive information. This is exactly why [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) and [RFC Specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3) discourages to use GET requests to send sensitive information. You should POST if you are sending the CSRF Token.

> What should I do make the site very secure? should I use any other
>   open source along with spring security to cover other attacks like
>   cross site scripting, etc.. ?

Spring Security framework is not a Silver Bullet. Using it won't magically make your web application 100% secure. Even though it covers most of the Security Vulnerabilities out there, we have to make sure to code in a way that doesn't introduce any.

For Example:

In the case of Cross site scripting even if you use Spring Security if you take in a value from an HTML input box and save it directly without HTML encoding it and display it back in a JSP file like `${value}` you will introduce the possibility for XSS.

Comment: Thanks Shazin, but I am not changing the state of the server via GET, I just use POST to submit Forms, so the CRSF token never appears on the URL.
All I want is to use GET to retrieve information from the server, like a list for example with some actions, so the user can submit the action using the POST. The problem here the page itself is GET, so the attacker can load it and open the source and get the token; so in this case I should keep all my pages as POST !! is that right !!